# Running a meteoris app crashes

Tags: meteor

When I'm learning meteor, I download an example app from [github](https://github.com/meteoris/chat), but when I run it, I get a crash like this:

```
W20160624-09:37:06.645(8)? (STDERR)           
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR) /Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR)                             throw(ex);
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR)                                   ^
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:21:15
W20160624-09:37:06.770(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:574:3
W20160624-09:37:06.771(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
W20160624-09:37:06.771(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160624-09:37:06.771(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160624-09:37:06.771(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
W20160624-09:37:11.188(8)? (STDERR)           
W20160624-09:37:11.189(8)? (STDERR) /Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
W20160624-09:37:11.189(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160624-09:37:11.189(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:21:15
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:574:3
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160624-09:37:11.203(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160624-09:37:11.204(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
=> Exited with code: 8
W20160624-09:37:14.763(8)? (STDERR)           
W20160624-09:37:14.764(8)? (STDERR) /Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:267
W20160624-09:37:14.764(8)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
W20160624-09:37:14.764(8)? (STDERR)                               ^
W20160624-09:37:14.779(8)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: meteorInstall is not defined
W20160624-09:37:14.780(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:21:15
W20160624-09:37:14.780(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/packages/meteoris_user.js:574:3
W20160624-09:37:14.780(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:283:10
W20160624-09:37:14.781(8)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
W20160624-09:37:14.781(8)? (STDERR)     at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/luke/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.lbyo5v++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
W20160624-09:37:14.781(8)? (STDERR)     at /Users/luke/WebstormProjects/chat/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:133:5
=> Exited with code: 8
```

Any idea how to fix this? Thank you very much.

Comment: It works fine for me. You could try run `rm -rf .meteor/local/` from Your project folder and then try `meteor`.

Comment: I think the problem could be with the commands you type in the console. Could you paste everything, include the running command?